# Convert SQL WHERE with COALESCE into LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to produce a filtered list in a controller to pass to a MVC view.

I know I can do this in SQL: (I've shortened the SQL somewhat...)

```
SELECT ItemID, Item, SupplierID, Supplier, BrandID, Brand, CategoryID, Category, SubCategoryID, SubCategory, TypeID, Type
FROM Table1 join Table 2... etc

WHERE   (supplierid = @SID OR @SID = -99)   AND
    (brandid = @BID OR @BID = -99) AND
    (categoryid = @CID OR @CID = -99) AND ....
```

but I would like to know the best way to do it in C# & Linq (or if it's just better to call a stored proc based on the above and use that instead)

Here is the start of my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? supplierid, int? itembrandid, int? categoryid, int? subcategoryid, int? itemtypeid)
{
    List<DTOClasses.ItemsListDTO> items = new List<DTOClasses.ItemsListDTO>();

    items = await (from i in db.Items  
                   join b in db.ItemBrand on i.BrandID equals b.BrandID
                   join s in db.Suppliers on b.SupplierID equals s.SupplierID
                   join sc in db.SubCategories on i.SubCategoryID equals sc.SubCategoryID
                   join c in db.Categories on sc.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID                  
                   where // get stuck at this point
                   select new DTOClasses.ItemsListDTO
                   {
                       ItemId = i.ItemID
                       //etc..
                   }
                   ).ToListAsync();

    return View(items);
}
```

I wanted to avoid having to write potentially 25 nested if statements if possible.

** Edit

for example - to keep the linq query neat and tidy, have each combination of input params with their own query to execute.

```
    if( BID != null && SID != null && CID != null)
{ query 1}
else 
if (BID != null && SID != null && CID == null)
{query 2}
```

Comment: What's a problem exactly? Where is COALESCE you mentioned in title? What 25 ifs you mean?

Comment: Your suggestion of a SPROC isn't all that bad, I probably would just `CREATE VIEW` though

Comment: @Mad Myche - I'm certainly more comfortable using a stored proc. more for consistency throughout the application that I'm trying to stick to using Linq queries than SP's. (if the controller needs to change, it's all in "one" place, rather than multiple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has the equivalent of COALESCE using the null coalescing operator `??`, but I am not sure how that is relevant to your question. C# also has the exact equivalent of multiple conditions with AND and OR in a where, so just like SQL you can do:

```
items = await (from i in db.Items  
               join b in db.ItemBrand on i.BrandID equals b.BrandID
               join s in db.Suppliers on b.SupplierID equals s.SupplierID
               join sc in db.SubCategories on i.SubCategoryID equals sc.SubCategoryID
               join c in db.Categories on sc.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID                  
               where ((b.BrandID == BID || BID == -99) &&
                      (s.SupplierID == SID || SID == -99) &&
                      (sc.CategoryID == CID || CID == -99))
               select new DTOClasses.ItemsListDTO
               {
                   ItemId = i.ItemID
                   //etc..
               }
               ).ToListAsync();
```

If the repetitiveness bothers you as much as it does me, you could hide it in a helper extension method, but that assumes the magic number stays the same -99 for all the ID types (and ignores how bad using a magic number actually is).

```
static class IDExt {
    static bool IDMatches(this int anID, int testID) => testID == anID || testID == -99;
}
```

then you have

```
where b.BrandID.IDMatches(BID) && s.SupplierID.IDMatches(SID) && sc.CategoryID.IDMatches(SID)
```

Comment: Thanks NetMage. I know using magic numbers isn't great... it's just a work around to avoid writing the combination permutations as I've highlighted in my edit above. (though magic numbers certainly make the example smaller)

I'm still quite new to c#, predominantly SQL where I'd make a dynamic query to update the joins & where clauses based on which parameters were not null

I did look at overloading, but thought that would still result in me coding several different permutations.

Comment: Ah. Well, nothing says you can't build up the Linq predicate dynamically with lambda syntax or look into dynamic Linq, but that would need the 25 if statements. Unfortunately since your criteria variables are separate, there isn't an easy way to loop over them.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case. Was hoping there was a "lazy" way to do it, but without that lazy way being an awful hack. Thanks again for your help. I have upvoted your answer... but as I have a low rep (SO obviously replicates real life here ;) ) it hasn't marked it up.